# Adding an image to the picture via coding in Visual Basic 2015

Tags: vb.net

For school, I'm trying to make it so that if i click on a button, then the picture box will display an image.

I've done the usual thing like
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("a certain path\image.jpg"), but because it is always in a certain path, if I send this to my teacher, then my path will be different to his (e.g. the path for my picture is G:\New Folder\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\image.jpg) but my teacher will most likely not have the image in that exact path.

Thanks

Comment: Use a relative path, and keep the image in the same folder (or subfolder) as the executable. Edit: to be clear, you'll have to give your teacher etc the folder containing the executable and image resource(s).

Comment: Rock-hard rule #1: never hard-code a path name.  Rule #2: never use a relative path.   Use Application.StartupPath and the Path class.  And the best solution, use Project > Properties > Resources.

Comment: @HansPassant makes a great point, `never hard-code a path name and never use a relative path`, it will turn around on you. On the other hand can you have where a user clicks the button and prompt them to select an image, then load that into the `PictureBox`...

Comment: you could also use an image from the internet? or you could look into the `SpecialFolder` and have it collect the image from there, or even us an `openfiledialog` and have your teacher select the picture they want to view

Comment: Hey Hans, I'm still relatively new to visual basic, so what I'm doing is a matter of guess work.

I assume by going to Project > Properties > Resources, I go and add my image to the resources.

I've done that but now how do I make it so if I click on the button the image displays in the picturebox? Is there a specific code?

Comment: nvm I got it.

Thank you all for your help